# Prevent Infinite loop in AMQP queue consumer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amqp, spring-amqp

I want to implement web flux client inside AMQP queue listener. I tried this:

```
@Component
public class TransactionGenesisAuthorizeListener {

    public TransactionResponseFactory transactionGenesisAuthorizeProcess(AuthorizeRequestFactory tf) throws Exception {

        AuthorizeResponse response = null;              

        try {           
                RestClient client = RestClientBuilder.builder()
                        .gatewayUrl(URL)
                        .build();

                Mono<AuthorizeResponse> result = client.executeAndReceiveAuthorize(request);
                response = result.block();

        return parseRawSuccessResponse(response);
    }

    private TransactionResponseFactory parseRawSuccessResponse(AuthorizeResponse response) {
        ................

        return obj;
    }

}
```

// web client

```
public Mono<AuthorizeResponse> executeAndReceiveAuthorize(AuthorizeRequest transaction) {
        Mono<AuthorizeRequest> transactionMono = Mono.just(transaction);
        return client.post().uri(checkTrailingSlash(gatewayUrl) + token)
                .header(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .body(transactionMono, AuthorizeRequest.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(AuthorizeResponse.class);
    }
```

Error log

```
2019-08-27 19:42:09,280 INFO  [stdout] (processingTransactionGenesisAuthorizeContainer-1) 19:42:09.280 [processingTransactionGenesisAuthorizeContainer-1] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ConsumerCancelledException
2019-08-27 19:42:09,282 INFO  [stdout] (processingTransactionGenesisAuthorizeContainer-1) 19:42:09.282 [processingTransactionGenesisAuthorizeContainer-1] INFO  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Restarting Consumer@6e537459: tags=[[]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,10), conn: Proxy@70156185 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@631ca718 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 49982], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

But unfortunately when I use wrong credentials for the connection of the web client I get infinite error message probably because AMQP client is resending the payload. Is there some way to trow exception and to stop re-sending the queue content and and again?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to catch an exception and wrap it into the `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`:

```
/**
 * Exception for listener implementations used to indicate the
 * basic.reject will be sent with requeue=false in order to enable
 * features such as DLQ.
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 1.0.1
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException extends AmqpException {
```

Also see some use-case in Docs in regards for this exception, as well as retry configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#async-listeners

Comment: Can you guide me a little but more I'm too junior for this. I tried to modify my configuration this way: https://pastebin.com/DYSWR1xy see the bottom. What I need to set for the constructor argument?

Comment: You can do like this `processingTransactionElavonSaleTemplate(null)`. Spring knows what to do to with such a construction and will return for you an appropriate bean. However it might be better to have the `CachingConnectionFactory` autowired into this configuration class and don't have that `connectionFactory` on all your `RabbitTemplate` beans. Also consider to have only one single instance for `RabbitTemplate`: fully not sure what drove you to such a fine-grained approach...

Comment: Can you please show me how to apply the configuration to `CachingConnectionFactory`? hm... Maybe by adding this configuration? https://pastebin.com/gJYAR4h8

Comment: Not sure what you mean from here... Your subsequent questions are not related to the original SO post.

Comment: ok, can you show me what global configuration I need to apply in order to limit the retry attempts for the Consumer queue?

Comment: No, retry is local configuration for particular `ListenerContainer`. So far you are good in that part. I just pointed that your configuration is too long for redundant beans. But, yeah... I agree it is not related to the question. So, you configure a retry for that container and that's all. You have it so far, and when you are ready to discard the message from the queue altogether, you throw that `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`. That's it.

Comment: I tried this `public TransactionResponseFactory transactionGenesisAuthorizeProcess(AuthorizeRequestFactory tf) throws Exception, AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException {` but get again infinite attempts. I my case I send the queue using `convertSendAndReceive`. Probably I need a different solution?

Comment: Not clear what you do, but `throws` is a contract of the method what to expect on the method consumer side. What you need in your case is a `throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException()` from your code, so listener container would know that the message must be discarded. you indeed can throw it from the retry recoverer when all the attempts are exhausted. I don't know what are those `TransactionResponseFactory` and `AuthorizeRequestFactory` types. If they are your own, then, please, don't confuse us: we definitely can't advocate your own code.